# Is the following π-system equal to the topology on the interval I

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets, measurable-sets

Consider $I$ an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now consider this set:
$ P=\left \{ I \right \}\cup \left \{(a,b),a\leq b, a,b \in I\right \}$.

This set is obviously a π-system and generates Borel's set. Is this equal to the topology on I ?

If not which set would belong to one and not the other ?

I know a topology is a π-system. How would you describe it if this isn't the one in question.

Comment: $P$ is clearly not a topology: it is not closed even under finite unions.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating ? A finite union of open sets does give an open set. I believe a union of elements from P would still be in I and still be open. If wrong could you explain why ?

Comment: @Catfoxes take, for example, $I=(0,1)$ and consider the intervals $(1/5, 2/5)$ and $(3/5,4/5)$. Both are in $P$ but their union is not as it is not connected.

Comment: I see thank you, this was the result of pour thinking. Thank you for giving an example ! I was only seeing the intersections.